# how can i inherit from both QWidget and QThread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I have a class like this

```
class GUI : public QWidget, public QThread
```

When I do the above i get errors about connect signals. `The error says Reference to "connect" is ambiguous`. Is there a way to inherit from both?

Thank you

Comment: Please explain why you want to do this. Since it can't be done (see answers) we'd like to know which of the things that *will* work to suggest to you. That requires more info.

Comment: my program receives messages from another computer through firewire. Messages received are directed to a file from where the GUI reads them. I want to handle firewire messages in one thread, and GUI in another thread.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't. Both `QWidget` and `QThread` inherit (non-virtually) from `QObject`. You therefore do not have virtual derivation, thus two copies of `QObject`, which confuses the compiler. `QObject` was specifically designed this way. See:

- http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2006-10/msg00711.html
- http://www.qtforum.org/article/23295/problem-opening-the-qfiledialog.html

There are some who allegedly went around this (can't find the link right now, but it's out there on Google, I had the same trouble two weeks ago), but it is unsafe at best.

Edit: the best way would probably be to have another object inherit from QThread and keep that object as a member in your `GUI` class. That is the sort of workaround most people do in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

`QWidgets` and GUI related objects con not be in different threads than the application main thread. You should not inherit both of them. You can not also call the `moveToThread()` function of a widget.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot inherit from multiple QObjects.

You can inherit from one and make the other a member variable and work from there.

```
class GUI : public QWidget 
{
  QThread myThread;
};
```

You've named your class GUI - is this the main GUI of your program? See the examples in the Qt examples folder - they have sample programs on both [GUI's](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/examples-mainwindow.html) and [Threads](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/examples-threadandconcurrent.html).

Comment: Only the main thread can operate on widgets, so making a widget a member of a thread seems odd.  What might this accomplish?

Comment: "you should be inheriting from QMainWindow" is false, you should only do that if you actually want some of the features provided by QMainWindow.  Any QWidget without a parent is automatically a window.