# Multiple inheritance with QThread and QWidget ( Multiple inheritance with QObject )

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-inheritance, qobject, ogre

I'm going to design `OgreWidget` class -A portable renderer widget with Qt.

(With my design), I think my class need to be inherited with `QThread` (for infinite render loop ) and `QWidget` ( target widget for ogre to render there) .

But according to many documentation and articles (for instance [this](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first)), Virtual inheritance with `QObject` is not supported .
Result of this inheritance will be such a error:

> `QObject` is an ambiguous base of `OgreWidget`

How should I resolve this problem ?

PS: In my old design , I create a separate `QWidget` , and Send It's `WId` to my `OgreWidget` as target widget. However, I'm now going to design a better and cleaner interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's impossible, because both `QThread` and `QWidget` in the end resolve to `QObject` base class

This thread answers your question:
[how can i inherit from both QWidget and QThread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595849/how-can-i-inherit-from-both-qwidget-and-qthread)

Comment: I'm sorry for my bad question !

Comment: I also found an interesting thread at
> http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2008-03/msg00575.html :)

Answer (score 0):

The `QThread` documentation is misleading, you don't need to and shouldn't be sub classing `QThread` here for your widget.

"You're doing it wrong" - http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/06/17/youre-doing-it-wrong/

You should either:

- Create a `QThread` `ogreThread`, create your `ogreWidget` and `ogreWidget.moveToThread(&ogreThread)`, or
- Create a `QThread` wrapper that allows you to tell it to create a new object of type T directly in the new thread.